# 1:1 relationship in SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, foreign-key-relationship, ssms

I want to create a 1:1 relationship in SQL Server Management Studio 2012, please help me, can't find the correct way, every time I try it creates a one to many relation.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a unique constraint or just include that information in the table itself.

The SQL Below should get you started:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
ADD CONSTRAINT myOneToOneColumn UNIQUE (myColumn);
```

Comment: is there a way to do it in the design mode?? I mean not by code

Comment: I'm sure there is.  Why don't you want to do it this way?

Comment: I think its easier that way.. Anyway I found how to do it here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx

Comment: Using the UI can definitely be easier when you are getting started.  Don't be afraid to branch out to use actual SQL as you get more comfortable with SQL Server.  You may find it's quicker.

Comment: You should NEVER design using the GUI as all of your code to create objects should be in script and then put into source control. Once you have data inteh objects, it can also be a problem if you change using a GUI. DO not get into this extremely bad habit, but write SQL xcode that can be source controlled and deployed like any other kind of code.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, a 1 to 1 relationship is a 1 to n relationship with an `unique` constraint added to the column which corresponds to the `n` part of the relationship.

So what you need to to is add a `unique` constraint to the foreign key.